# Message error "ENOENT: no such file or directory"

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, directory, next.js13

I created a project with the command "npx create-next-app@latest" and when I want to start a production server with the command "npm start" I get the following error:

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/enzo/proyectos/clientes/AndreaVittoriTraducciones/cliente/.next/BUILD_ID'] {
errno: -2,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: '/home/enzo/proyectos/clientes/AndreaVittoriTraducciones/cliente/.next/BUILD_ID'
}

I know that the file is there and the path is correct because when I run the "npm run dev" command it starts it in development mode correctly. I also know that the application is using the correct directory because it generates it with an error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a production build first you run **npm run build** in your project terminal and then run **npm start** this will create a optimized production build and start the project in production server.